# Sending data / information to the client side?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I am using the Express web framework and trying to figure out how to send data / information to the end user.

I know that I can easily send strings using `res.render` and putting it into JSON format.

Example:

index.js

```
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});
```

index.hjs (Using Hogan templating)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
    <p>Welcome to {{ title }}</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

The title of the page will be "Express" and the welcome message will contain it.

How exactly would it work with variables and other functions that I have that require constant updates / need to push text in real time?

Comment: it will perform well if after loading the page you will call your php code with **AJAX** requests... that way users still have te UI and the requests will perform their operatrions in the background

Comment: my bad.. the meaning was to create an ajax call to your server url that uses the router.get function

Comment: Do you have an example of what that would look like?

Comment: here is a link with a very basic demo of ajax: **http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_post2**. if you can use jQuery the code will be even simpler: **http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_get**

Comment: Do you have any example on how this would work with Node.js?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65654/discussion-between-ymz-and-user3024130).